# How to use custom flash player inside android app

Tags: android

I've a custom flash player(as .swf file). Is it possible to use that custom flash player on my android app? If it so, how could i do that? Example links are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an html file with embedded swf file. See sample here http://pastebin.com/BYrfKmea After that you can make it in three different ways

- You can put html and swf files in assets folder and try opening it in a `WebView` by `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/player.html");`. Main disadvatage of this method is flash is not working in `WebView` sometimes.
- Put html and swf files in assets folder. Then programmatically copy them to SD card. How to do that find out here [How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard) Then open copied file in browser by calling `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/player.html")));`
- Place html and swf fles on a web-server and open in browser by `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yoursite.com/player.html")));`. Disadvantage of this method is that you need internet connection and a web-server ready for high-load.